# Count items in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my database

[image]

I want to count `Bikes` which are currently available in a `RouteCode` in a SAME EXPIRY WEEK. So if EXPIRY WEEKs are different, the `RouteCode` can reappear, otherwise the `RouteCode` has to display with the `BikeQuantity` it has.

This is my problem. The `RouteCode = G` shows up 2 times with 1 bikes each even though they are expired in a same week. How can I say it has 2 bikes in `BikeQuantity` column?

[image]

Comment: please don't post images instead post some data and your code

Comment: date are different that's why it showing separate counts

Comment: Can you post the data from your three tables so that we can see what's going on?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2998271)

Comment: @Nino El - Please recreate the tables again either manually or in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and show your expected output based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you are `GROUP`ing by 'FoundDate'. You need to group by 'ExpiryWeek' if you want to aggregate (i.e. sum) the number of bikes on a per-ExpiryWeek basis.

The second problem is that you are `SELECT`ing 'FoundDate' and 'ExpiryDate'. You cannot select these columns if you're grouping on 'ExpiryWeek' because there's no way to aggregate the data (dates) in those columns*. It follows that you should not order by 'ExpiryDate' (since this column won't appear in the output table).

( * ...because if you have two entries for a given expiry week but with different a 'FoundDate' for each, what would you expect to see in the result table in the 'FoundDate' column for that row?)

Change your `SELECT` clause to this:

```
SELECT li.RouteCode,
    DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, FoundDate)) as ExpiryWeek,
    COUNT(b.BikeId) As BikeQuantity
```

and change your `GROUP BY` clause to this:

```
GROUP BY li.RouteCode, DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, FoundDate))
ORDER BY DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, FoundDate));
```

and your query should work.

(Because 'ExpiryWeek' is a calculated column, you have to supply the same calculation in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses - just specifying 'ExpiryWeek' won't work, at least for some variants of SQL. There are ways around this: for example, you could use a 'With' clause. See this answer for examples which avoid duplication: [How to group by a Calculated Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900999/how-to-group-by-a-calculated-field))

Based on the latest code you have posted, the correct query should be:

```
select li.RouteCode,
            DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, b.FoundDate)) as ExpiryWeek,
            COUNT(b.BikeId) as BikeQuantity

FROM dbo.Bike b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contact ct ON b.ContactId = ct.ContactId    
    INNER JOIN dbo.LocationInfo li ON li.PostCode = ct.PostCode

WHERE DATEADD(day, 30, FoundDate) >= GETDATE()

Group by li.RouteCode, DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, FoundDate))
ORDER BY DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, FoundDate));
```

Comment: Appreciated, Neil. That is what I was trying to do and I understand that percisely. But seems like it missing something. I have got this error.
----
Column 'dbo.Bike.FoundDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. ----
Btw, should the GROUP BY be like this
Group by li.RouteCode, DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, FoundDate))
ORDER BY DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(WEEK, 4, FoundDate));