# How to connect two SQL queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I want to connect the following two queries:
(First query)

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN date_trunc('month',d) = date_trunc('month', NOW()) 
THEN NOW()ELSE d+interval '1 month' - interval '1 day' END as lastday
FROM generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, NOW(),'1 month') as d
```

AND (2nd query)

```
Select * FROM TableA ta 
LEFT JOIN TableB tb on ta.id = tb.id
```

The first query gives me the last day of some specific months. I want to use those days in the where clause of the second query.
I was thinking about putting the first query into a LEFT JOIN in the 2nd query. But I don't know what do write in the "ON" Part.
Also, I don't exactly know how a "Nested Select Statement" might look like

My goal is to use the last days in the 2nd query like that

```
Select * FROM TableA ta 
LEFT JOIN TableB tb on ta.id = tb.id
where lastday [do something]
group by lastday
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Well i gues then i have to open another thread. Because its just a part of the whole "problem"

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to join table with only one column. And that what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea. Could you get things you want to du like this:

```
SELECT
    ta.d as day, 
    CASE
        WHEN date_trunc('month', d) = date_trunc('month', NOW()) 
            THEN now()
        ELSE 
            date_trunc('month',d)+interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
    END as lasday
FROM
    TableA ta
    LEFT JOIN TableB tb ON ta.id=tb.id
HAVING -- This works like WHERE but for calculated values. 
    lasday ....
```

Then if you have to use that `lastday`in your group by -clause, refer to this conversation: [How to group by a Calculated Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900999/how-to-group-by-a-calculated-field)

Comment: "d" is the result set of the generate_series function and not a column in TableA or TableB

Comment: Oh yes,of course. Could you add simplified data model from tables on your question and result you are looking for.