# How to explicitly access a new column in SQL from GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite.

I reduced my problem to this query:

```
WITH list_5([value]) AS (VALUES(1),(2),(3))
SELECT (t1.[value] * 2) AS [value], SUM(t1.[value]) AS [sum] 
FROM [list_5] t1 
GROUP BY value / 2;
```

I want SQL to group by the *new* `value` column, instead of the old one.

I can explicitly refer to the old value (`t1.value`), but how do I refer to the new one?

No matter what I do, `group by` uses the old value of `value`, instead of the column that's multiplied by 2.

The obvious solution would be to change the column names to unique names. But that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I didn't know SQLite could run a SQL statement like this. Isn't it malformed?

Comment: Why ask? Just try it and see that it works..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Fixed it. I think someone edited my code and added a typo. Anyway should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use positional notation:

```
SELECT (t1.[value] * 2) AS [value], SUM([t1.value]) AS [sum]
FROM [list_5] t1 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Or give it a name that does not conflict with a table column:

```
SELECT (t1.[value] * 2) AS computed, SUM([t1.value]) AS [sum]
FROM [list_5] t1 
GROUP BY computed;
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking something different.

Comment: I should have emphasized that positional notation won't work, because I want to do an operation on it (which is why I divided there in 2, to demonstrate the intent)

Comment: @Erez . . . Rename it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the same sql operation in the `Group by` clause instead of alias,

```
WITH list_5([value]) AS (VALUES(1),(2),(3))
SELECT (t1.[value] * 2) AS [value], SUM([t1.value]) AS [sum] 
FROM [list_5] t1 
GROUP BY (t1.[value] * 2);
```

Comment: Won't that duplicate the computation?

Comment: Is that an official sqlite feature? Will it also work on more complicated columns?

Comment: Its a Sql standard, across all the databases

Comment: This is not the same query as the OP, but looks like the right way to go here +1.

Comment: @JimMacaulay Can you please provide a reference for it? I searched but couldn't find it.

Comment: It appears that perhaps it's not so simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900999/how-to-group-by-a-calculated-field