# Why is GROUP BY not working in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 500
        BusinessDate,
        BRANCH_CO_MNE,
        RIGHT(TRANS_INPUTTER, 5) 'USER_ID',
        CASE
            WHEN TRANS_TYPE LIKE '%Deposit%'
            THEN COUNT(*)
                END 'No of Cash Deposit'
FROM    test_link.MMBL_phase2.dbo.EB_MMBL_H_UAR_PROT
WHERE   BusinessDate = '2023-01-23'
GROUP BY    BusinessDate,
            BRANCH_CO_MNE,
            TRANS_INPUTTER,
            TRANS_TYPE
ORDER BY    USER_ID
```

Which returns the following results:

| BusinessDate | BRANCH_CO_MNE | USER_ID | No of Cash Deposit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 10938 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 10938 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 10938 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 10938 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 10938 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | 18 |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | NULL |

The `NULL` values are repeating while I have put the `No of Cash Deposit` in GROUP BY clause.

Shouldn't the results be like

| BusinessDate | BRANCH_CO_MNE | USER_ID | No of Cash Deposit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 10938 | NULL |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | 18 |
| 2023-01-23 | BNK | 11748 | NULL |

Comment: `'No of Cash Deposit'` is the name of the last calculated column. It is not used in the query in any other capacity.

Comment: Group by can be applied on values only. NULL is no value, but indicates there is no value. Could you please provide some sample data of your table and the expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group by a Calculated Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900999/how-to-group-by-a-calculated-field)

Comment: `GROUP BY` groups by `TRANS_INPUTTER, TRANS_TYPE` as well. I'd bet if you add those columns to `SELECT` you'll see the rows aren't duplicate

Comment: The aggregate inside the `CASE` has a smell of not being correct.  I suspect you should be wrapping the `COUNT` *around* the `CASE` for a conditional aggregate.

Comment: @GSerg: Yes this is just the name of the column but I have used `TRANS_TYPE`. And I was referring to that. Sorry my bad

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: That didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is your attempt at conditional aggregation. For conditional aggregation the aggregation function doesn't go inside the `CASE` expression, the `CASE` expression is put inside the aggregate function. As a result of your method, you *have* to `GROUP BY` the column `TRANS_INPUTTER` because it's not being aggregated.

If you switch to conditional aggregation, then you can remove `TRANS_TYPE` from the `GROUP BY`. Also, you then need to change the `GROUP BY` on `TRANS_INPUTTER` to be `RIGHT(TRANS_INPUTTER, 5)`.

```sql
SELECT TOP (500)
       BusinessDate,
       BRANCH_CO_MNE,
       RIGHT(TRANS_INPUTTER, 5) AS USER_ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TRANS_TYPE LIKE '%Deposit%' THEN 1 END) AS [No of Cash Deposit]
FROM test_link.MMBL_phase2.dbo.EB_MMBL_H_UAR_PROT
WHERE BusinessDate = '2023-01-23'
GROUP BY BusinessDate,
         BRANCH_CO_MNE,
         RIGHT(TRANS_INPUTTER, 5)
ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

Comment: Please stop adding noise comments, @NaumanKhan . They've been removed for a reason.

Comment: I was just thanking you for the help @Larnu. And I thought the comments were not getting posted properly so I would re-comment. Sorry for that. Plus, I have been banned from asking further questions. Please help me with that! I am relatively new for understanding the norms of SO

Comment: See this FAQ article, @NaumanKhan : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 2):

You are also grouping on TRANS_INPUTTER and TRANS_TYPE. When those values are different, you will have also rows for those even if you don't specify them in your SELECT statement.

However as we don't have scripts for testdata I cannot reproduce your problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 500
    BusinessDate,
    BRANCH_CO_MNE,
    RIGHT(TRANS_INPUTTER, 5) 'USER_ID',
    CASE
        WHEN TRANS_TYPE LIKE '%Deposit%'
        THEN COUNT(*)
            END 'No of Cash Deposit'
FROM    test_link.MMBL_phase2.dbo.EB_MMBL_H_UAR_PROT
WHERE   BusinessDate = '2023-01-23'
GROUP BY    BusinessDate,
        BRANCH_CO_MNE,
        RIGHT(TRANS_INPUTTER, 5),
    CASE
        WHEN TRANS_TYPE LIKE '%Deposit%'
        THEN COUNT(*)
            END 
ORDER BY    USER_ID
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).